# What is passed to the success function in an Ajax delete request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

I am currently working on a React-Rails app and am trying to figure out how to pass a deleted record to a parent component from the success function to update the parent component's view.

Here is the code in question:

```
handleDelete (e) {
  var that = this;
  var url = "/records/" + this.props.data.id;
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      that.props.handleDeleteRecord(data);
    }
  });
}
```

The console.log(data) above returns undefined.

My problem is that Ajax doesn't seem to be passing anything to the success function. Is that true?

Comment: jQuery's ajax call will put in `data` as passed to the success handler whatever your ajax call returns so you need to see what data the ajax call is actually returning.

Comment: Look at your records controller to see what it's returning, if anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the Rails `RecordsController` so that it renders some type of data after the request. I recommend JSON.

```
def destroy
  record = Record.find(params[:id])
  record.destroy
  render json: record
end
```

With that you will have the JSON form of the record that you just delete passed back to the success function of the AJAX call.